# Pizza toppings with array

Tags: java

I'm suppose to write a program, Pizza.java, that lets the user enter up to 15 toppings for a pizza, then prints out the toppings in alphabetical order. Also, the toppings should be listed with numbers.

A sample output would be like this

[image: A sample output would be like this]

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Pizza {
 public static final int numbers=15;

  public static void main(String[] args) {


  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  String []toppings;
  System.out.println("Enter a toping (or type quit): ");

  String a= input.nextLine();

 // how do I add String a to the array toppings?   
  int count=1;
  while (!a.equals("quit")&&count<numbers){
     System.out.println("Enter a topping (or type quit): ");
     a= input.nextLine();
     if(!a.equals("quit"))
        // how do I add String a to the array toppings?     
     count++;


  }
    if(count==numbers)
     System.out.println("No more toppings allowed.");
     int i=1;
     Arrays.sort(toppings); //sorts the array in alphabetical order
    while (int i<=count){
  System.out.println(i+". "+Arrays.toString(toppings));      
  }

     if(a.equals("quit")){
      Arrays.sort(toppings); //sorts the array in alphabetical order

      while (int j<=count){
      System.out.println(j+". "+Arrays.toString(toppings));      
       }
  }






        }



         }
```

How do I complete this code?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you really want to use a static array you have to initialize it with its fixed size. For you this would be String[] toppings = new  String[numbers];

Then while iterating up to your numbers value you can access the array by index and assign a value with toppings[count] = a;

But you should start with int count = 0; because indexing of an array in java starts with zero, else you would get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

But for your use case you would be better of with using an ArrayList because you don't always want to add 15 toppings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason I can't set it up like String[] toppings = new String[numbers]; is because I don't know the size. It could be a size of 1 if the user decides to quit after inputting only one value.

Comment: Then just use an ArrayList as I mentioned in my edit a few moments ago.

Comment: BTW, the entry for your first `toping` will be discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simpler using List instead of arrays:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza {
    public static final int numbers = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int attempt;
        for (attempt = 0; attempt < numbers; attempt++) {
            System.out.print("Enter topping topping (or type quit): ");
            String topping = input.nextLine();

            if (topping.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            toppings.add(topping);
        }

        if (attempt == numbers) {
            System.out.println("No more toppings allowed.");
        }

        Collections.sort(toppings);

        for (int position = 0; position < toppings.size(); position++) {
            System.out.println((position + 1) + ". " + element);
        }
    }
}
```

or using arrays:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza {
    public static final int numbers = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] toppings = new String[numbers];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int attempt;
        for (attempt = 0; attempt < numbers; attempt++) {
            System.out.print("Enter topping topping (or type quit): ");
            String topping = input.nextLine();

            if (topping.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            toppings[attempt] = topping;
        }

        if (attempt == numbers - 1) {
            System.out.println("No more toppings allowed.");
        } else {
            // Remove "null" elements from "toppings" array
            String[] temp = new String[attempt];

            for (int position = 0; position < attempt; position++) {
                temp[position] = toppings[position];
            }

            toppings = temp;
        }

        Arrays.sort(toppings);

        for (int position = 0; position < toppings.length; position++) {
            String element = toppings[position];

            System.out.println((position + 1) + ". " + element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently, I am not allowed to use List<String> and System.out.printf("%s. %s\n", position + 1, toppings.get(position));. I am to complete the code only using arrays.

Comment: why such ? If I may ask.

Comment: @user547075 added solutions only with arrays.

Comment: @Haramoz probably some university requirements (it's normal that something "is forbidden"  )

Comment: Could you tell me what break; is?

Comment: in the for-loop change to "int position = 1" to start counting from 1. and not 0.

Comment: @user547075 currently there is only one `break` which break loop after typing `quit`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are not allowed to use an `ArrayList`. Here is my approach on how to do it using a String array. The most interesting part for you should be the `Arrays.copyOfRange` method, which you could also substitute with a `System.arraycopy(...)` call.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza {
    private static final int MAX_TOPINGS = 15;
    private final String QUIT_KEYWORD = "quit";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Pizza().printToppings(MAX_TOPINGS);
    }

    public void printToppings(int maxTopings){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] toppings = new String[maxTopings];

        int count;
        for (count = 0; count < maxTopings; count++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter topping topping (or type %s): ", QUIT_KEYWORD);
            String topping = input.nextLine();
            if (topping.toLowerCase().equals(QUIT_KEYWORD)) {
                break;
            }
            toppings[count] = topping;
        }

        if (count+1 == maxTopings) {
            System.out.println("No more toppings allowed.");
        } else {
            toppings = Arrays.copyOfRange(toppings, 0, count);
        }

        Arrays.sort(toppings);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + ". " + toppings[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For the following input:

```
Enter topping topping (or type quit): Cheese
Enter topping topping (or type quit): Onions
Enter topping topping (or type quit): Tuna
Enter topping topping (or type quit): quit
```

You would receive this output:

```
1. Cheese
2. Onions
3. Tuna
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't bother with while loops. If you are dealing with arrays, you should use a [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop.

As far adding a string to the array is concerned, you should really [learn about arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) before trying to use them. You did not even initialize your array before using it.

You can use a [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement to exit the loop when the user enters "quit".

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza {
    //If actually want the user to be able to enter 15 toppings, then set numbers to 16.
    public static final int numbers = 16;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Initialize the array
        String[] toppings = new String[numbers];

        int count;
        //Use a for loop
        for (count = 0; count < numbers; count++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a toping (or type quit):");
            toppings[count] = input.nextLine();
            if (toppings[count].equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                //If they enter quit, break from the loop
                break;
            }
        }

        if (count == numbers)
            System.out.println("No more toppings allowed.");

        //If they do not fill all 15 indices of the array, trim out the empty indices.
        if (count < numbers)
            toppings = Arrays.copyOfRange(toppings, 0, count);
        Arrays.sort(toppings);

        //Use another for to print them
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + toppings[i]);
        }

    }

}
```